# NSURL delegate didReceiveData method not called

Tags: nsurlconnection

I know this has been discussed in a lot of other posts but I need to post it because those threads have not helped me unfortunately. I am trying to connect to a rails server which returns some data in JSON format in response to a GET request.I have implemented the four methods for NSConnectionDataDelegate as listed below

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [resultData setLength:0];

}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
[resultData appendData:data];


}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");

    NSString *errDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
    NSLog(@"%@",errDesc);

}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveLoading");
}
```

In the connectionDidFinishDownloading method (not listed) I carry out the JSON parsing but that fails since **resultData** is empty since didReceiveData method is never called.

The didReceiveResponse method is called because I see the message being logged. The server is running on localhost so I can confirm the request is received and using Charles I know the response is correctly received in JSON format. So there seems to be no problem on the server side. But the didReceiveData method is never called. Neither is didFailWithError method.

Can someone please help me with this? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. This is the first time I am working with NSURL so it would be much appreciated. I am working on iOS 5 with ARC.

Satyam

**Edit:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?%@", kDevelopmentMode ? kLocalHost : kHost, endpoint, parameters]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that your app is not getting data back. Try this with your url it will let you know the raw data returned, and the jsonserialization if data is returned.

```
NSData *returnedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURLHere"]];

if (returnedData) {
    NSLog(@"returnedData:%@", returnedData);

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnedData options:kNilOptions error:Nil];
    NSLog(@"jsonDict:%@", jsonDict);
}
else
    NSLog(@"Got Nothing");
```

if your log displays the raw data and the json data then The issue is with your NSURLRequest. But if the log displays "Got Nothing" then there is a problem with what your trying to get.

**EDIT**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AsyncImage : UIImageView 
{    
    NSMutableData *activeDownload;
    NSURLConnection *imageConnection;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *activeDownload;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *imageConnection;
- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url;
@end



#import "AsyncImage.h"

@implementation AsyncImage
@synthesize activeDownload;
@synthesize imageConnection;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"dealloc AsyncImage");

    [activeDownload release];
    [imageConnection cancel];
    [imageConnection release];
}

- (void)cancelDownload
{
    [self.imageConnection cancel];
    self.imageConnection = nil;
    self.activeDownload = nil;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Download support (NSURLConnectionDelegate)

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.activeDownload appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Clear the activeDownload property to allow later attempts
    self.activeDownload = nil;

    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    self.imageConnection = nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.activeDownload];

    self.activeDownload = nil;

    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    self.imageConnection = nil;
}

- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url {
    if (self.imageConnection!=nil) { [imageConnection release]; } //in case we are downloading a 2nd image

    self.activeDownload = [NSMutableData data];
    // alloc+init and start an NSURLConnection; release on completion/failure
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:
                             [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] delegate:self];
    self.imageConnection = conn;
    [conn release];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi I tried what you suggested and I do get the raw data and the json data printed to the log as expected. But I do not understand what is wrong with my NSURLRequest. Do you have any pointers? I have added my request code as an edit. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing you used this url in the code I gave you: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?%@", kDevelopmentMode ? kLocalHost : kHost, endpoint, parameters]]; If you did then your url and your json data is good. I will supply my code in an edit. See if that works for you.

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong. I had implemented the didFinishDownloading method of the NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate since I thought that would be the method called when all the data was received. When I removed the delegate from the class definition and removed the method everything works as intended. You answer made me wonder why I was implementing didFinishLoading and the other method. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Set `NSURLConnectionDelegate` in the .h file.